# Best way to parse JSON in Rails for Twitter API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, twitter, rubygems

I'm working on a **rails app** that searches the Twitter API stream for keywords and then records those tweets.

I've used Hpricot before to parse XML but I was wondering if someone could **recommend a gem** (or even a best practice) **to parse JSON** from the Twitter search API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the newly rewritten Twitter gem, you can make a query like this:

```
Twitter.user_timeline("sferik").first
```

The response would be a [Hashie::Mash object](https://github.com/intridea/hashie) corresponding to the first status. To access the information, you just call the attribute like it was a method:

```
Twitter.user_timeline("sferik").first.text
```

The response from this is just text. You don't have to directly deal with JSON.

Comment: If you're using the Twitter API, I would definitely go with the twitter gem. If you're just parsing arbitrary JSON, then you might want to look at a gem like the JSON gem or HTTParty if you're parsing HTTP requests.

Comment: Awesome will give this a shot

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are many twitter gems that should work. Github has the [twitter](https://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter) gem as the most popular.

I have used it 1 1/2 yrs ago, but it should do what you want and have support to back it up.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [json](http://rubyforge.org/projects/json) gem to parse Twitter responses. To access the api I use [grackle](https://github.com/hayesdavis/grackle) and sometimes [curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb) to do api requests in parallel (Curl::Multi).